# User Profile REST Endpoint isn't up-to-date

Tags: 2013, rest, user-profile, user-profile-service

I'm trying to access the User Profile information so that I can personalize some information on our Intranet.

I'm using the User Profile REST endpoint for it, but it seems like the REST endpoint is not up-to-date.

This is the result in the REST for Afdeling (Departement):

> ```
>    - <d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
>     <d:Key>Afdeling</d:Key> 
>     <d:Value>Kommunikation</d:Value> 
>     <d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType> 
>     </d:element>
> ```

But this is old information. Checking my User Profile in Central Administration the same field lists this:

[image: Cut-out from CA]

I'm querying:

```
http://'mysite'.dk/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getmyproperties
```

Has anybody had this problem before?

Comment: Apparently, our User Profile Syncronization isn't running in production. I'll post an answer here, if this'll solve the problem. Just need the "server guys" to set it up :o)

Comment: Robert, you were right. Apparently the User Profile Service had a script that synchronized with SAP. And that script wasn't running. So thanks a lot.